# Imitate PHP urlEncode bahaviour in Javascript for ñ Ñ ü Ü " for a utf-8 string

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8, urlencode, url-encoding

currently Im forced to emulate a `PHP urlEncode` using a `Javascript` for a `utf-8` string

so far I got this...

```
var s = "%FNuserMsgToEnc%";

function urlencode(str) {
  str = (str + '').toString();
  return encodeURIComponent(str)
    .replace(/!/g, '\%21')
    .replace(/'/g, '\%27')
    .replace(/\(/g, '\%28')
    .replace(/\)/g, '\%29')
    .replace(/\*/g, '\%2A')
    .replace(/\%20/g, '+')
    .replace(/~/g, '\%7E')
    .replace(/Ñ/g, '\%C3%91')
    .replace(/ñ/g, '\%C3%B1');
}

WScript.Echo(urlencode(s));
```

but the script won't run with the last to lines, cuz it says it something wrong with the syntax

```
        .replace(/Ñ/g, '\%C3%91')
        .replace(/ñ/g, '\%C3%B1');
```

I would like to include the `ñ Ñ ü Ü "` for a `utf-8` string, how can I do it???

thanks advanced.

Comment: What exactly is the error message? could you please post it here? Are you forced to do it manually? have you tried [encodeURI](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeURI.asp)?

Comment: I agree with @Brnpzs - The question is too vague and does not provide enough information about the issue you are having. Also `WScript.Echo` is part of VBScript, not PHP. So is this a PHP question or VBScript?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why not just use the javascript function that does this.  encodeURIComponent

Comment: its an action script inside WinAutomation (a macro recorder for windows environment), I guess thats why it looks similar to VBScript. But I'm shure that this script is made to imitate PHP urlEncode in Javascript, the action is called "Run Javascript" it's a Javascript, how can I urlEncode de ñ character??

Comment: In javascript, you can use `encodeURI()` i.e: `encodeURI("cumpleaños")`. The output will be "cumplea%C3%B1os"